# Hamiltonian in gravity with $\Lambda =0$ and using it to generate time translations

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-gravity

Time translation is generated by Hamiltonian. In gravity, the bulk Hamiltonian for closed $d$ hypersurfaces (obtained by ADM decomposition of $d+1$ spacetimes) is 0. This is basically a constraint of the Einstein-Hilbert action. Upon the imposition of these constraints on the Hilbert space we obtain the Wheeler deWitt equation:

$$H|\psi\rangle = 0.$$

This leads to the so-called "problem of time". However if we have a non vanishing boundary contribution to gravity, we can talk about a notion of time. An example of this is in AdS, where we can talk about a "boundary time".

I am really confused about $\Lambda = 0$, with stress energy = 0. We don't require a boundary notion of time here, but here time is defined canonically because the spacetime is invariant under Lorentz transformations. It seems apparently that we don't need to invoke any boundary notion of time. So my question is the following: Is there really a boundary notion of time given by boundary Hamiltonian for $\Lambda =0$, and is it related to Lorentz invariance of the spacetime? Also is any such boundary Hamiltonian invariant under asymptotic symmetries?